# Rails 3 assign values for a has_many association with select

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, select

I have a `Problem` model that `has_many` Issues. My Issue model `has_many` Problems. I have a join table on both called `issue_problems`, with its own model that `belongs_to` both Issue and Problem. In my Problem form, I'm trying to assign issues to a problem with a select tag. (The issues have already been created, so I'm just assigning to the problem.) I've tried it out but am getting the following error:

```
undefined method `reject' for "3":String
```

And the stack error:

```
app/controllers/problems_controller.rb:12:in `create'
```

*NOTE: I plan on implementing something in the future that allows me to assign multiple issues to take advantage of the `has_many`, but for now I'm just trying to assign one issue with a select*

Here's my code:

**My Issue model**:

```
class Issue < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, :presence => true, :on => :create

  has_many :issue_problems
  has_many :problems, :through => :issue_problems
end
```

**My Problem model:**

```
class Problem < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :body, :presence => true
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :solutions
  has_many :issue_problems
  has_many :issues, :through => :issue_problems

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :solutions, :issues
end
```

**My IssueProblem model:**

```
class IssueProblem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :problem
  belongs_to :issue
end
```

**My create action on the problems_controller:**

```
def create
  @problem = current_user.problems.new(params[:problem])
  @solution = @problem.solutions.new(params[:problem][:solution])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @problem.save
      @problem.issues << @problem.issue
      @solution.save!
      @solution.update_attributes(problem_id: @problem.id, user_id: current_user.id)
      format.html { redirect_to(@problem, :notice => 'Problem was successfully created.') }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @problem, :status => :created, :location => @problem }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @problem.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

**My form:**

```
<%= form_for(@problem) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :published_at, :value => Time.now %>
  <% if @problem.errors.any? %>
  <div id="errorExplanation">
    <p>Halt! Just so you know, you have to fix these <%= pluralize(@problem.errors.count, "error") %> before you can ask a question:</p>
    <ul>
    <% @problem.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li>-&nbsp;<%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="input-container">
    <%= f.text_field :body, :placeholder => "What's your problem?" %>
  </div>
  <%= f.fields_for :solution do |f| %>  
    <%= f.hidden_field :published_at, :value => Time.now %>
  <div class="input-container">
    <%= f.text_field :body, :placeholder => "What solution do you propose?" %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.select :issue_ids, Issue.all.collect {|x| [x.name, x.id]}, :prompt => "Select an issue" %>
  <div id="button">
  <%= f.submit 'Add', :class => 'button' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the error?

Comment: Just added that to my question.

Comment: it's difficult to see which line caused the problem. Please post the exact stack trace - 3 levels should be enough.

Comment: That's actually the only line from the stack trace. It targets the first line in the create action on problems_controller: `@problem = current_user.problems.new(params[:problem])`.

Comment: This line does not call 'reject'. The error you get is "undefined method `reject' for "3":String". In the stack trace, it should give you the series of calls that resulted in this error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you needn't IssueProblem model. You should put "has_and_belongs_to_many" in Issue and Problem model like following:

```
class Issue < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :problems
end

class Problem < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :issues
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought HABTM was a bit more restrictive in general, so that's why I went with a join table.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open enough to watch **8. Associations - many -to -many** section in [this](http://www.lynda.com/Ruby-on-Rails-3-tutorials/essential-training/55960-2.html?srchtrk=index:1%0Alinktypeid:2%0Aq%3aruby%20on%20rails%0Apage:1%0As%3arelevance%0Asa%3atrue%0Aproducttypeid:2%0Ameta_software_facet%3aRuby%20on%20Rails) link, then I think you will be clear enough with everything.

Watch [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association) **railscasts** and understand everything from the scratch.

### EDIT:

Though your problem is solved, let this be a pointer to people who visit here for a deep insight on many-to-many associations in ROR.